# PHP add one day in period of daylight saving

Tags: php, date

I am in Brazil and we changed to summer time this saturday.

I have a loop that genrates timestamps for midnight for every day in a selected timerange.
So I get the timestam of the first day:

```
$start = 1413255600; // 2014-10-14 00:00:00
$end is some date in the future
```

And now I ahve a loop

```
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i = strtotime('+ 1 day', $i)) {
   echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $i);
   echo "<br>";
}
```

This outputs:

```
2014-10-14 00:00:00
2014-10-15 00:00:00
2014-10-16 00:00:00
2014-10-17 00:00:00
2014-10-18 00:00:00
2014-10-19 01:00:00
2014-10-20 01:00:00
```

Shouldn't php/the server now that is there was the time change and add only 23 hours on the 19th?
What am I doing wrong?

My timezone is correct and the server autimaticly changed to summertime on saturday.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a loop that genrates timestamps for midnight for every day in a selected timerange.

That's your first problem - assuming that midnight even exists. Whether or not that's true depends on your definition of midnight.

In the Brasilia time zone (and probably others in the region), 2014-10-19 00:00:00 didn't occur. The local times went:

```
2014-10-18 23:59:58
2014-10-18 23:59:59
2014-10-19 01:00:00
2014-10-19 01:00:01
```

So your script *is* doing the right thing - it's added one day to `2014-10-18 00:00:00` and come up with a reasonable answer: `2014-10-19 01:00:00`. You're then asking for one day after *that* value (1am) which is entirely reasonably 1am on the 20th.

If you want "the earliest time of day on each date" then you should make sure that `$start` is a date which *does* have a midnight, then add 0 days, 1 day, 2 days, 3 days etc to `$start` - rather than repeatedly adding *one* day. I'm not a PHP developer, but it seems to me that using [`DateTime::Add`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) would be a better approach to this than using `strtotime`.

Answer (score 3):

As per Jon Skeet's answer, here's how to do it using PHP's `DateTime()` classes.

```
$start    = $start = (new DateTime('@1413255600'))->modify('midnight'); // Start date
$end      = new DateTime('2014-10-22'); // End date
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');    // Interval of one day
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end); // Period object to iterate through

foreach ($period as $date) {
   echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   echo "\n";
}
```

**Reference**

- [DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [DateInterval()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)
- [DatePeriod()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

[Demo](https://eval.in/207965)